# check if All routes is authentificated netcore 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I need to find a open-source program to check if all routes of my mvc application (net core 3.1 )is auhtentificated.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the purpose of that? If you are afraid you might forget to require authentication on an endpoint you should just configure this as the default in Startup

Comment: in my application I have routes which must be submitted to authentication and others not, I just wanted to do a check

Comment: But what's the purpose of the check?

Comment: add missing authorizations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question, but I have a feeling what you're actually looking for is a way to ensure that you don't "accidentally" forget to make a route require authentication. The best way to do this is to require authentication everywhere by default and then specifically choose which route should not require authentication.

In ASP.Net Core you can do this with a default authorization policy:

```
// Startup.cs - ConfigureServices
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

Now, authentication is required **everywhere**.

If you want to allow public access to some routes, you'll configure that with an attribute on the specific routes:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class PublicController : Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

... or for a specific action:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult PublicAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the addition of controllers at startup to:

```
services.AddControllers(o =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```